# Unreachable " after 'Return' Warring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to be able to fix these warnings:

1. Combine this with the previous "var"statement, that is on line 7, 9 and 10.
2. Unreachable " after 'Return' - on where is  if `($window.width() <= 770) { return;`

**Here is the script:**

```
     //StickyBox
     $(function () {
         $.fn.scrollBottom = function () {
             return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
         };
         var $StickyBox = $('.detailsBox');
         var $window = $(window);

         $window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
             var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
             var footer = 288 - $window.scrollBottom();
             var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

             $StickyBox.css({
                 top: 'auto',
                 bottom: 'auto'
             });

             if ($window.width() <= 770) {
                 return;
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: '0',
                     bottom: 'auto'
                 });
             }

             if (scrollTop < 50) {
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     bottom: "auto"
                 });

             } else if (footer > gap - 100) {
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: "auto",
                     bottom: footer + "px"
                 });

             } else {
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: 80,
                     bottom: "auto"
                 });
             }
         });
     });
```

Also is there anyway to change the following script, so I don't need to give a number, but it should know when the header reaches the box and then make its position fixed?

```
if (scrollTop < 50) {
$StickyBox.css({
bottom: "auto"
});
```

Live example of the above code here: http://loaidesign.co.uk/php/projects.php?project=1

Comment: `return` exists the function. The code following the return will never execute.

Comment: What part of the messages don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is if this "if" is true, then it will always return, and the next fiew lines of code can NEVER get run.

```
if ($window.width() <= 770) {
                 return;
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: '0',
                     bottom: 'auto'
                 });
             }
```

sof if you want to set top:0 and bottom: auto  you have to put the return after that.  If you mean to only set top and bottom if it's NOT true, then you're missing an else:

```
if ($window.width() <= 770) {
                 return;
             }else{
                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: '0',
                     bottom: 'auto'
                 });
             }
```

maybe you mean

```
if ($window.width() <= 770) {

                 $StickyBox.css({
                     top: '0',
                     bottom: 'auto'
                 });
                 return;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1:**

I cannot tell which lines are 7, 9 and 10. But it has to do with the way you assign values to your variables. They can be comma seperated:

```
var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10,
    footer = 288 - $window.scrollBottom(),
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
```

**2:**

When you return the rest of the method is not executed. Therefor `$StickyBox.css()` would never get called. if `$window.width() <= 770` is `true`. I believe you either want to remove the `.css()` call, or return after it's called.

```
if ($window.width() <= 770) {
   return;
} else {
   $StickyBox.css({
      top: '0',
      bottom: 'auto'
   });
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make the StinkyBox function to stop working when screen size is below 770px and run again when it's above that width

Comment: Answer updated. If it's less than 770, then stop everything by returning. Else run code.